# What is a simple explanation of Decorators in JavaScript and how useful is it in functional programming

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, decorator

What are decorators in javascript in comparison with HOCs.

I have a good mental model of HOCs and therefore want to use as my frame of refernce to understand decorators.

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI, decorators are not part of the standard, their syntax and functionality are still being discussed as a [Stage 2 Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators).

Comment: Same idea, different paradigm...

Comment: Decorators are specific to classes, if you're referring to https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators . As long as you don't mix OOP and FP, they aren't useful.

Comment: In this [article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1491/attaching-new-behaviors-through-decorators-in-javascript) , you can find the implementation of the decorator by using two different approaches - functional and class-based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to give a simple example. Suppose you want to make an `Animal` and the animal can have functionality of `eat`, `sleep` and `make noise`. Now, you create a `Dog` by extending animal (classical inheritance pattern). `Dog` will override the `make noise` function to `bark`, `eat` to `carnivores` etc. A cow will override the `make noise` function to `Moo`, `eat` to `herbivores`. This is all good but then comes a point where the `Mountain Dog` doesn't even `make noise`. What we would do is pick the `make noise` function and put that in `Cow` and for `Dog`, we have different functions in classes for `make noise`. This was a simple example where the classical inheritance makes the code prone to un-scalability because the requirements change all the time and that's when functional programming comes to rescue with `decorator` pattern. For the above example, I won't care about the `type` of animal. I'll have different functions for each functionality.

```
function eat(type) {
    //I'm carnivores, herbivores
    console.log(`I'm ${type}`);
}

function makeNoise(noise){
    //bark, Moo
    console.log(`I ${noise}`);
}

function sleep(sleepingWay){
    console.log(`I ${sleepingWay}`);
}

Now, we can define animals as by decorating empty `Animal` as: 

cow = compose(eat('herbivores'), makeNoise('Moo'))(Animal)
dog = compose(eat('carnivores'), makeNoise('Bhu'), sleep('at day'))(Animal)
mountainDog = compose(eat('carnivores'), sleep('at day'))(Animal) //I don't make noise
```

I'm not writing the actual code. I'm just giving an idea about why we should use it.

The other benefit of using functional programming is that, the testing becomes super easy because you have to test individual functions and while coding in react, it saves a lot of your time and energy. I use [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) all the time and don't even use the `class` keyword.

You have to take care that all the functions are `pure` and the state is `immutable`. Hope this helps. Let me know if you need further understanding

Comment: this is very helpful, so recompose is the decorator pattern. Thanks @ajay-gaur